# What does 様子を見るだけだ mean here?

Tags: meaning

Can someone assist me with understanding the below?

「最後まで参加したい気持ちはわかるが、無理はしない方がいい」

「身体を動かすことになるんだから。そんな様子では……」

「心配のし過ぎだ」

「今は寝起きだから。情けないことに、昨日の疲れがまだ残っているのかもしれない」

「朝食を食べれば、すぐに元通りになるさ。さあ、早く寮に戻ろう」

「……わかった」

「だが、**様子を見るだけだ**。体調が変だと思ったら、正直に言って欲しい」

「わかった」

I don't quite follow what is meant by 様子を見るだけだ in this context.
I know of the expression 様子を見る e.g.

https://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E6%A7%98%E5%AD%90%E3%82%92%E8%A6%8B%E3%82%8B

but I don't quite follow how だけ is modifying this expression in this case as it doesn't make sense to me do be "only" or "just" doing that.

Answer (score 2):

"様子を見る" generally means things like "see how things are", "size up the situation", "test the water", "check the condition (of someone/something) "etc.

Seeing as Person A isn't exactly in tip-top condition but is set to participate in some kind of physical activity, and Person B, worried about them, says: "だが、様子を見るだけだ。体調が変だと思ったら、正直に言って欲しい", I think by "様子を見るだけだ" they are telling Person A that it'll be just a "test run", to see how fit they are to play, so please don't go all out, will you? -- or something along those lines  -- adding that if they are feeling off, they need to tell them. (My, that's a lot of third person plural pronouns.)

There's nothing unusual about this instance of だけ. Just another day at the office for it, imposing limits on people and things.

Comment: I reduced you third person plural pronouns by one ;)

Comment: @user3856370 Ooh thanks! I was trying out my Free Indirect Style but apparently it was poorly executed.